What is a realistic growth for a world index fund?
I had a meeting with a financial adviser recently.
I told him I was investing in various index funds and I was assuming a growth rate of 7% (minus inflation at 2.6% and fees at 0.4%) so 4% in real terms.
He felt this was too optimistic and a more realistic rate of return would be 2% above inflation.
I asked if that was a pessimistic and therefore safe assumption as my plans involve me working ad-hoc post retirement to plug any gaps, so happy to pick a realistic return as I should be able to adapt if required.
The adviser explained that 2% was a realist return based on years of past performance.
Since the meeting, I've reviewed 20 years of data from the FTSE All World here:
https://curvo.eu/backtest/en/market-index/ftse-all-world?currency=eur
and note an average return of 10%, which if I include inflation (actual values for the UK) and fees, it returns an average real world growth of 6.5%.
Why does my research yield such a significant difference in growth rates compared to that from a financial advisor?

Only 2% long-term annualized growth above inflation seems small; What is the nature of the conversation you were having with this advisor? Are they trying to get you to move money into their management, and invest in particular products? Typically the concern with advisors is that they actually over-promise possible outcomes, so the fact that they appear to be highly conservative may be context that isn't clear, or some other thing.

And was the advisor assuming/ expecting that some of the index funds you'd be invested in would be bond funds (particularly as you close in on retirement)?  Inflation + 2% would be a reasonable baseline for a portfolio that included a decent chunk of bonds.

It sounds like they are just being conservative, either about future growth or inflation, or both - "hope for the best, plan for the worst".  Inflation in the last 3 years has been much higher than the 17 before that, so it's not unreasonable to think inflation will be higher going forward than the current 20-year average.

It was a one off meeting with a FA where it was clear that I'm not intending on having my funds managed and there was no upsell in terms of investment products. It was a simple 1 hour session for a sanity check. It was clear that my funds where 100% equity index funds, and I named the Vanguard funds I was using. It was clear I was avoiding bonds, and he agreed that was sensible with decades left before retirement.

I have always seen (and heard, and read...) that the average return in the US at least is 7%. This is already including inflation since the real return of the SP500 has been closer to 10%.

"There was no upsell in terms of financial products" - Are you sure about that? Seems to me like they are discouraging you from self-management, but being overly conservative about your expected returns.

I can't answer about a world index fund, but if you were talking about the S&P500 fund your assumptions would be low.  But I feel your reasoning is sound and conservative.
Several large brokerage firms offer very low cost funds, so even a fund fee of .4% is high.  But it is safe to say that some combination of fund fees and inflation could total as high as 3%.  The S&P500 fund has returned 10.1% so figuring a growth rate of 7% is considered conservative.
Its my personal opinion you can get away with planning for a 9% growth, doing this for about 15 years I have tended to outpace such a plan.  You will get raises, bonuses, and probably make additional contributions.  So planning for 9% is reasonable here in the US.
Now, realistically you may only achieve a 2% growth with a financial adviser and there are a few reasons why.  In fact in your case I would expect lower with a financial adviser:

Their fee, typically 1% sometimes higher for lower balances.  So even your 4 is now 3.
They will probably direct you into higher cost funds.  Now your 3 becomes 2 or lower.
They will probably recommend you have a fairly conservative allocation.  Even for young people they might recommend bonds as high as 10 or 20%.  this cuts your ability to grow assets.  Even less return.  (For me being close to retirement, I still have less than 10% in bonds.)
They tend to over estimate inflation.  When the truth of the matter is retirees see costs decrease as they age.  Every financial projection I have seen has retirees spending much more at 85 than 65.  The opposite is true to life.
They might recommend dumb investments like gold.  This will cut your earnings even more.

So you are not crazy which is my answer to your question.  If you want to earn less, but have more peace of mind use a financial adviser.  They are instrumental for some people.
However they are not necessary for many of us and a lot of money can be saved by avoiding them.

Great answer. A 2% expected return over decades is laughable. The advisor is either an extreme pessimist or is trying to downplay market returns in order to sell another "investment" like universal life.

My pessimistic view would add that the "advisor" was trying to downplay the passive investments to further his own agenda. My more positive view would be that he is was just very conservative because we've had decades of amazing stock returns and it's possible that we will see years of less than average returns (the average of the last 20 years). The real answer is in his head and most likely somewhere in between.
